# how to get the second level text from the leaf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik, treeview

How to get the second father if my position was the leaf .

for example :

> 1---->2---->3
>
> or
>
> 1---->2---->3---->4
>
> or
>
> 1---->2---->3---->4---->5

if i'm in the last node  (`3 or 4 or 5`)

How to get the text of node (2)?

---

```
    foreach (RadTreeNode node in nodeCollection)
    {
        if (node.Nodes.Count == 0)//leaf
        {
            if (!node.Value.TrimEnd().Contains('#'))
            {
                GroupDetails grp_d = new GroupDetails();

                grp_d.Boss_code = 0;
                grp_d.Boss_name = string.Empty;
                if (node.Value.TrimEnd().Split('_').Count() > 2)
                {
                    grp_d.Boss_code = int.Parse(node.Value.TrimEnd().Split('_')[2]);
                    grp_d.Boss_name = node.Value.TrimEnd().Split('_')[3];
                }
                grp_d.Dep_code = int.Parse(node.Value.TrimEnd().Split('_')[0]);
                grp_d.Dep_name = node.Text.TrimEnd() //Here i want to get the second parent text to concatenate  
                grp_d.Dep_year = int.Parse(node.Value.TrimEnd().Split('_')[1]);
                grp_d.Group_id = res;
                grp_det.Add(grp_d);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not being funny but wouldn't the obvious solution to be to find the root node recursively while passing both the parent node and the current node into the recursive function? If the "parent" node has no parent itself, return the "current" node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RadTreeNode node_tmp = new RadTreeNode();
      node_tmp = node;
          while (node_tmp.ParentNode != null)
                {
                   p_txt = node_tmp.Text.TrimEnd();
                   node_tmp = node_tmp.ParentNode;

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while( node.parent != null )
 node = node.parent;

return node.child;
```

Assuming you only have one child (i.e. node (2))

Just suggesting a logical way of traversing the tree. Implementation is up to you and your system design!